# String index out of range error on my game of life code

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, conways-game-of-life

```
    package edu.bsu.cs121.mamurphy;

    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

// Maurice Murphy
// CS121
// 10/17/15

public class GameOfLifeMain extends JFrame {

    // Intitial reading and printing of the world

    public GameOfLifeMain() {
        super("Game of Life");
        setSize(600, 445);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        Test test1 = new Test();
        test1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        panel.add(test1);
        setContentPane(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        Temp one = new Temp(test1);
        one.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] asd) {
        new GameOfLifeMain();
        System.out.println();

    }
}

class Temp extends Thread {
    Test anim;

    public Temp(Test anim) {
        this.anim = anim;

    }

    public void run()// for each instance of test begin will be executed
    {
        anim.begin();
    }
}

class Test extends JPanel

{
    final static int numOfRow = 25, numOfCol = 75;
    final static char DOT = '.';
    static char[][] grid = new char[numOfRow + 2][numOfCol + 2];
    static char[][] nextgrid = new char[numOfRow + 2][numOfCol + 2];
    boolean sameFlag;
    boolean blankFlag;

    public static void init(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        for (int numOfRow = 0; numOfRow <= numOfRow + 1; numOfRow++) {
            for (int numOfCol = 0; numOfCol <= numOfCol + 1; numOfCol++) {
                grid[numOfRow][numOfCol] = DOT;
                nextgrid[numOfRow][numOfCol] = DOT;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void pause() {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread();
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public void begin() {
        init(grid, nextgrid);
        read(grid);
        repaint(); // calls paintComponent
        pause();
        while (sameFlag == true && blankFlag == false) {
            nextGen(grid, nextgrid);
        }
    }

    public static void read(char[][] grid) {
        Scanner world = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type the file name of the world you'd like to create.");
        String fileName = world.nextLine();
        {
            try {
                world = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Please insert a valid file name.");

            }
            ;

            for (int numOfRow = 1; numOfRow <= numOfRow; numOfRow++) {
                String s = world.next();
                for (int numOfCol = 1; numOfCol <= numOfCol; numOfCol++) {
                    grid[numOfRow][numOfCol] = s.charAt(numOfCol - 1);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void print(Graphics g) {
        int x, y;
        y = 20;
        for (int numOfRow = 1; numOfRow <= numOfRow; numOfRow++) {
            x = 20;
            for (int numOfCol = 1; numOfCol <= numOfCol; numOfCol++) {
                g.drawString("" + grid[numOfRow][numOfCol], x, y);
                x = x + 7;
            }
            y = y + 15;
        }
    }

    public static int neighbors(char[][] grid, int r, int c) {
        // counts the # of closest neighbors that are X's
        int count = 0;
        for (int numOfRow = r - 1; numOfRow <= r + 1; numOfRow++) {
            for (int numOfCol = c - 1; numOfCol <= c + 1; numOfCol++) {
                if (grid[numOfRow][numOfCol] == 'X') {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (grid[r][c] == 'X') {
            count = count - 1;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void nextGen(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        for (int numOfRow = 1; numOfRow <= numOfRow; numOfRow++) {
            for (int numOfCol = 1; numOfCol <= numOfCol; numOfCol++) {
                if (grid[numOfRow][numOfCol] == 'X') {
                    int count = 0;
                    {
                        if (grid[numOfRow][numOfCol - 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow][numOfCol + 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow - 1][numOfCol] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow - 1][numOfCol - 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow - 1][numOfCol + 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow + 1][numOfCol - 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow + 1][numOfCol] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow + 1][numOfCol + 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                    }

                    if (count == 2 || count == 3) {
                        nextgrid[numOfRow][numOfCol] = 'X';
                    } else
                        nextgrid[numOfRow][numOfCol] = DOT;
                }
                if (grid[numOfRow][numOfCol] == DOT) {
                    int count1 = 0;
                    {
                        if (grid[numOfRow][numOfCol - 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow][numOfCol + 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow - 1][numOfCol] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow - 1][numOfCol - 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow - 1][numOfCol + 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow + 1][numOfCol - 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow + 1][numOfCol] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[numOfRow + 1][numOfCol + 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                    }
                    if (count1 == 3)
                        nextgrid[numOfRow][numOfCol] = 'X';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void copy(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRow + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfCol + 1; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = nextgrid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        boolean blankFlag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRow + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfCol + 1; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] != DOT) {
                    blankFlag = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return blankFlag;
    }

    public static boolean isSame(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        boolean sameFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRow + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfCol + 1; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == nextgrid[i][j]) {
                    sameFlag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return sameFlag;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);// erases panel Contents
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        if (sameFlag == false && blankFlag == false) {
            print(g);// or whatever method you use to print the world
        } else {
            if (sameFlag == true) {
                g.drawString("The worlds are repeating!", 10, 250);
            }
            if (blankFlag == true) {
                g.drawString("The world is blank!", 10, 250);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So I am coding this for an assignment in my CS121 java class, and it is for Conway's Game of Life. The idea behind the code is that the user types in a file name (a text file) which has a grid of periods and x's. A period is a dead cell and an x is a living cell.

When I try and type in the file name, it automatically throws me to the exception and says `Please insert a valid file name.`

If I try and type in the file name again, it gives me this error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at edu.bsu.cs121.mamurphy.Test.read(GameOfLifeMain.java:103)
    at edu.bsu.cs121.mamurphy.Test.begin(GameOfLifeMain.java:79)
    at edu.bsu.cs121.mamurphy.Temp.run(GameOfLifeMain.java:46)
```

So the one answer I have gotten says that I need to put my prompt asking the user for the file name within a loop that only happens when the file name successfully opens. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

After you catch the exception trying to open the file, your code continues into the loop to read from the file (which was not opened). Since the scanner (world) is still assigned to System.in, your next attempt to enter the file name is processed as the first row in the file. Since the name you input is shorter than the expected number of columns, you get an index out of range exception at 's.charAt(numOfCol - 1)'

You need to put your prompt for the file name in a loop, which exits only when the file is successfully opened.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not seeing how to implement the loop. Would it be a for loop, a while loop? Is there some kind of operation you can preform on the file where it's like file.fileName(Open)? I am sorry if this is a stupid question.